# Limit number of records for a model

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a django model and I would like to limit the number of records of it than can exist in the database. 
For example, let's say I have a radio and it can have 6 different configurable stations - what is the best way to limit the number of stations in the database?

Comment: I don't think every database backend has a row limit feature, but why do you want this on db level anyway? Do the people using the program access the db directly? Why can't you use a model save or form save function to handle the limit?

Comment: A question to clarify: do you want a permanent number of station or user can configure this number?

Comment: A permanent number, not configurable.

Comment: @AmirRachum I did not get your comment. Please do not forget to specify the user.

Comment: @sergzach There is only one radio, and it has exactly 6 stations. It's a hardware limitation, so the amount of stations is not configurable. There will never be more than 6 stations in the radio.

Answer (score 4):

You implement this by overriding the [`save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) and checking that for each radio there are only six stations. If the seventh station is being added, you can abort the save with an appropriate error message.

Comment: Am I understand correctly that, if so, we must to do an extra 'select' to find out if the count is correct?

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can create one radio model with a single instance (singletone-like) and create 6 stations as one-to-one fields. Please see the possible decision.

The advantage is you can have **random access** to each station. There are no any more checkings.

```
class RadioHasNotStationError( Exception ):
    pass

class _Station( models.Model ): # private model, so, you can't use the class anywhere else
    # fields of station

class Radio( models.Model ):
    station1 = models.OneToOneField( _Station )
    station2 = models.OneToOneField( _Station )
    station3 = models.OneToOneField( _Station )
    station4 = models.OneToOneField( _Station )
    station5 = models.OneToOneField( _Station )
    station6 = models.OneToOneField( _Station )

    def set_station( self, num, val ):
        try:
            setattr( self, 'station{0}'.format( num ), val )
        except AttributeError:
            raise RadioHasNotStationError( "The radio has not station {0}".format( num ) )

    def get_station( self, num ):
        try:
            result = getattr( self, 'station{0}'.format( num ) )
        except AttributeError:
            raise RadioHasNotStationError( "The radio has not station {0}".format( num ) )
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def get_inst():
        try:
            result = Radio.objects.select_related().get( id = 1 )
        except Radio.DoesNotExist:
            result = Radio.create()
        return result 

radio = Radio.get_inst()
radio.station1 = new_station
# ...
radio.set_station( 5, new_station2 )
# ...
station4 = radio.get_station( 4 )
# ...
radio.save()
```